# Highcharts + add sub headers / group in legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to create a [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) legend with sub headers instead of just a legend title?
example:

standard legend looks like:

```
**countries**
- series A
- series B
- series C
- series D
```

I would like to be able to create something like:

```
**countries**
- series A
- series B
**regions**
- series C
- series D
```

This seems like an easy task to do, but cant find anything in the [API documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend) that would allow me to do this, thanks for your help/advice

Comment: I don't think that possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts: structure legend by subtitles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039738/highcharts-structure-legend-by-subtitles)

Comment: Actually yes, my question is similar to the one above, and must have missed that one, however that one didn't get a correct answer/solution yet and is an old post. meanwhile highcharts api has developed over the years and more people have started using it, i think Core972 is right, there is no way of doing this or is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have subtitles but the way I have done this in the past is to use a fake series:

- Set up a fake series for each subtitle with no data
- Hide the symbols in the legend by setting `marker: { radius: 0 }` and  `lineWidth: 0` on each of the subtitle series
- Remove the onclick (show/hide series) events from each of the subtitle items

See JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/zzella/ac575ur5/3/

Your issue will then be pulling your subtitles to the left (if you want them to appear left aligned with the symbols rather than text). I've shown an example of how to do that in the fiddle but obviously you'll have to change it so it's not hardcoded or come up with a cleaner way of doing it!

Of course, you could also just create your own custom HTML legend to replace the default Highcharts one and not have this problem!

Comment: Thank you for your response and solution, Ella. I have marked this as the correct answer, despite it needs some work doing, but it got me underway to resolve this issue, hope highcharts are watching and implement this feature in newer versions as it seems a logical option.